# How to count the number of row with select count(*)

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo

I tried to get the number of row using select count(*) with multiples parameters and encode it on JSON Format, but i got this :

```
{"notification":[{"count(*)":0}],"message":[{"count(*)":0}]}
```

Instead of excepted :

```
{"notification":0,"message":0}
```

There is the code of the page here :

```
session_start();
require_once __DIR__ . '/mysql/Db.class.php';
$bdd = new Db();
$t = array();

$query = $bdd->query("SELECT count(*) FROM notification WHERE id_proprio = :id_proprio AND readed = :readed", array("id_proprio"=> $_SESSION['userid'],"readed"=>"0"));
$query_2 = $bdd->query("SELECT count(*) FROM discussion WHERE id_1 = :uid AND readed = :readed AND notifPour = :uid2 OR id_2 = :uid3 AND readed = :readed2 AND notifPour = :uid4", array(
  "uid"=> $_SESSION['userid'],
  "readed"=>"0",
  "uid2"=> $_SESSION['userid'],
  "uid3"=> $_SESSION['userid'],
  "readed2"=>"0",
  "uid4"=> $_SESSION['userid']
));


$t["notification"] = $query;
$t["message"] = $query_2;

echo json_encode($t);
```

Including a part of the class Db :

```
public function query($query,$params = null,$fetchmode = PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
{
    $query = trim($query);

    $this->Init($query,$params); // INIT IS THE CONNECTION TO DB

    if (stripos($query, 'select') === 0) {
        return $this->sQuery->fetchAll($fetchmode);
    }
    elseif (stripos($query, 'insert') === 0 ||  stripos($query, 'update') === 0 || stripos($query, 'delete') === 0) {
    return $this->sQuery->rowCount(); 
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

How can I get the excepted result format like this :

```
{"notification":0,"message":0}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your MySQL API returns an array of all the rows, and each row is an associative array whose keys are the labels in the `SELECT` clause. You need to extract the values from the arrays:

```
 $t["notification"] = $query[0]['count(*)'];
 $t["message"] = $query_2[0]['count(*)'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify your SQL query to begin with:

```
SELECT count(*) AS cnt FROM
```

And then fetch the values from queries as such:

```
$t["notification"] = $query[0]["cnt"];
$t["message"] = $query2[0]["cnt"];
```